# Moving Netbeans Projects folder to cloud

Tags: netbeans, dropbox, onedrive

I have a Netbeans project I've been working on for several years. When travel Export it to Zip file from Netbeans, copy the zip to a thumb drive or Dropbox, and import it to Netbeans on my laptop.

I'm now thinking about just MOVING the entire C:\Users\jag_m\Documents\NetBeansProjects folder to OneDrive (or Dropbox). Is that going to work, or will it cause me a lot of grief?

Comment: github private repository is by far the best bet

Comment: Don't know anything about github. Could I simply move my Netbeans Projects folder there then work on a project as if it were on whatever machine I happened to be using? I.e., like Dropbox ot OneDrive?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up a private [git](https://git-scm.com/) repository at [Github](https://github.com/). Git is designed for exactly what you need plus SO much more. Not only will you have access to your code on "whatever machine", it offers rollbacks, merging, branching, and remote repositories etc etc.

If I recall, you can now make private repositories for free.

I'd highly suggest using [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), it makes learning and understanding git simple.

Comment: Got it. I think I just created my first Netbeans/Git project on my PC. No will try accessing it from my Laptop. Thanks for the nudge :-)

Comment: I can create a Git Local Repository for a simple existing Netbeans Project but can't Push it to a Remote Repository. I've seen a video of the process and read several step by step docs, but it always fails to connect. There are numerous online reports of this problem online, mostly pretty old.

Comment: Are you using the github desktop app?

Comment: No. I'm hoping to work within Netbeans and the github desktop app seems to be focused on working with files rather than Netbeans Projects. If I'm missing something in that regard, please enlighten me.

Comment: In the end, its all just files anyway. I'm not familiar with the Netbeans and Github integration so I cant help you there. Alternatively, the Github Desktop app makes it really simple.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll use the git desktop to keep the local NB project directories synced with a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the source of my NB Push connect problem. It simply times out while trying to connect, perhaps to a reported Windows 10 problem. If I just keep clicking Next after a failure it eventually works!

Comment: After rebooting my router the Push is connecting on the first try. I expect there was a problem with the server Spectrum was assigning to my router.

Comment: Correction: It's the cable modem that has to be rebooted.